# n2439 rationale behind "Extending move semantics to *this" limitations to non static member functions

Tags: c++

What is the rationale behind n2439:

> 12.1.4 A constructor shall not be declared with a ref-qualifier.

and

> 12.4.2 A destructor shall not be declared with a ref-qualifier.

Assuming some class A with some costly ref counting semantics, i would write something like this, so as to be able to avoid retain/release-ing temporary objects:

```
struct B {
  A a;
  B (const& A a) & : a(retain(a)) {}
  B (const& A a) && : a(a) {}

  ~B () & { release(a); }
  ~B () && { }

  void do_something_with_a();
};

A a = getA();
auto b = B(a); // retain+released
b.do_something_with_a();       
B(getA()).do_something_with_a();  // no retain / release
```

Answer (score 1):

Intrusive reference counting like this is 20+ year old technology. It exists in such arcane places as COM and objective-c.

In their day these technologies were useful and helped us move forward (and a few steps back) but things have moved on. We have become wiser.

Nowadays we understand that separating the concerns of lifetime from function is a more sensible way to go. It allows decoupling of concepts, cleaner code that's easy to reason about.

This is why the standard has `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`...

...but no `std::intrusive_base` or `std::intrusive_ptr`.

Because these concepts are actually harmful.

Having reset our internal code-writing guidance systems so that we write nicely decoupled code, we find that we don't need to optimise constructors this way - if we want a reference to A we simply take a reference to A, if we want a copy of a `shared_ptr` to it, we simply copy the `shared_ptr`.

Code does what it says on the tin. There is no hidden magic. Suddenly, code with reference-counted objects can be reasoned about, we don't have to remember whether we need to release an object or not.

Welcome to the post c++11 world. It's wonderful :-)

Comment: This was the C++03 world too. It's just that you needed to use the widely-accepted _de facto_ standard Boost libraries, rather than the ISO ratified ones.

Comment: Sadly, I am in a situation where i do need to interoperate with a "20+ year old technology"... This was just a code sample, in my case, A would be a raw pointer to an opaque library object, in such situation, shared_ptr seems overkill when the library objects are already reference counted. Anyway this was more of a sample code, the initial question was more an inquiry about the rationale behind the limitation, if that was more a design decision to promote good practices or some compatibility issue, or something else.

Comment: @gsigms Yup, I know the problem, but you can't blame the standards committee for locking that crap out of the future, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes of course, but boost also had the concept of the intrusive pointer - the lessons had not been fully learned at that point.